# Spring Cloud - Zuul Server error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulServer {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(ZuulServer.class, args);
     }
 }
```

application.yml

```
  eureka:
    client:
      enabled: true
        serviceUrl:
           defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/v2/

  zuul:
    proxy:
       route:
         service1: /myservice1
         service2: /myservice2
```

Example calls:

```
http://localhost:8080/proxy/myservice1/users
http://localhost:8080/proxy/myservice2/auctionlots/today
```

Predecoration filter works during routing getting following error (using 1.0.0.M2) :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixExecutableBase$ObservableCommand.toBlocking()Lrx/observables/BlockingObservable;
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixExecutableBase.queue(HystrixExecutableBase.java:342)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixObservableCommand.queue(HystrixObservableCommand.java:50)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixExecutableBase.execute(HystrixExecutableBase.java:296)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixObservableCommand.execute(HystrixObservableCommand.java:50)
        at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:485)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:162)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:86)
        at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
        at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197)
        ... 41 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

@vladsfl My [sample app](https://github.com/spencergibb/communityanswers/tree/so27040684) with your provided code works.  That particular error comes from having an incompatible version (likely old) of rxjava.  The version in my sample (and the version that works with hystrix) is `com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-core:jar:0.20.6`.  Can you provide your configuration?  What version of rxjava do you have?